# Performing long running operation in onDestroy

Tags: java, android, multithreading, lifecycle, jmdns

I have a "long-running" cleanup operation that I need to perform in `onDestroy()` of my `Activity`. What is the best way to do this?

If I use a `Thread` to do this, my `onDestroy()` will return immediately; but what happens to the Thread reference? I am looking for advice on any implications/gotchas/trip-wires that I need to be aware of here since I assume that the process will still be alive even after the Activity is destroyed.

---

### Background:

I am using [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net) in my app. When the user is done with my app, I want to clean up the JmDNS instance. I do this using the `close()` method of `JmDNS` class. However, this method takes **more than 5 seconds** to complete. As a result, the user sees my `Activity` on screen for a long time after touching the Back key.

I am yet to figure out why the `close()` takes that long, but in the meanwhile I also realized that I really don't need to wait for the close to complete successfully. All I need is a way to "trigger" the close and be done with it.

Comment: Jmdns is usually used for discovering network service, I don't know the reason why you need keep it open and running until application finally closed. I usually close it immediately once I found the remote server and done with it, and prompt user a ProgressDialog in the mean time.

Comment: Yes- that is my normal use case. I have another use case where I need to continuously monitor for service being discovered/dropped and take action accordingly, throughout the life time of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing what I had asked in the question - I start a `Thread` to perform the long-running operation in `onDestroy()`.

One case I had to consider was when the user re-opens my app even before the long-running has completed. In my app, this means a new instance of JmDNS gets created. So, I clean up each instance separately in my `onDestroy`.

Your use case might differ - you might want launch the cleanup thread only if it is not already running (using `Thread`'s `isAlive()` method or some such technique).

Here's some sample code. To appreciate the "clean up each instance separately" part, perform the following sequence of steps:

1. Launch the app
2. Press the back button. You will see the clean up operation in LogCat
3. Re-launch the app.
4. Again, exit the app. Now, you will see two sets of cleanup logs - the first one representing cleanup for the first instance; and the second set corresponding to the second instance.

   ```
   public class DelayedExitActivity extends Activity {

       private static final String LOG_TAG = "DelayedExit";
       private final  Runnable longOperation = new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               for (int i=0 ; i < 50; i++){
                   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Iteration "+i);
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       };
       private Thread longThread ;

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           if(longThread == null){
               longThread = new Thread(longOperation);
           }
           longThread.start();
           super.onDestroy();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Just a heads up to those reading this solution. It will work but note that this will keep an implicit reference to the activity and you will have a memory leak for as long as this operation is active.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your thread in `onBackPressed()` and call `destroy()` when your thread will be finished.

Comment: Don't you mean I should call `finish()` once the thread finishes? In this case, what is the user expected to see upon pressing Back key?

Comment: Yes, i mean You should call finish(). Yuo can show ProgressDialog or anything else upon pressing back key.

Comment: I'm reluctant to make the user wait for my app to *close*! Since I'm not interested in the result of the cleanup operation, I was wondering if I can start the cleanup in a thread and simply continue with the `Activity` destruction. That way, the user immediately "exits" the app while the cleanup happens in the background. My only concern is what will happen to that background thread; and what will happen if user re-launches my app before that background thread has completed.

Comment: Nothing will happen if your application willn't use the same things that thread use

Comment: That won't handle switching to another activity and destroying later from stopped  state.